# android java onBackPressed deprecated

Tags: java, android, deprecated, onbackpressed

Why every SDK update it is more and more complicated ?

Who can find simplest to replace:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
 // Do stuff
 super.onBackPressed();
}
```

by:

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Do stuff

                // The next 3 lines replace: super.onBackPressed();
                setEnabled(false);
                getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
                setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }
```

I'm very upset about all deprecated things and additional security that remove feature like launching your app on url pattern (you must own the site to make it work!)

Comment: The replacement is entirely dependent on what 'do stuff' is. Show what you are actually doing.

Comment: The overall android development is now being shifted towards Jetpack Compose with kotlin by Google hence the old Java era APIs are being deprecated!

Comment: Do stuff can be anything, I just want the default behavior. I'm currently put a boolean to false to stop a detection loop.

Comment: @MohammedJunaid ok, but I don't like that, it's more setting things than develop

Answer (score 0):

As for me, all I just do when I need to make onBackPress...

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

Comment: In Kotlin maybe not in Java